# An example of a function that is analytic only on the upper-half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I've been asked to give an example of a complex function that meets the criteria outlined in the question above but I'm not sure if this is something I should know given an example or if its a result that can be derived from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Take your favorite analytic function for which all points of the unit disc are singular, say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{2^{n^2}}$. Then pre-compose it with a transformation that sends the upper half plane to the unit disc. For example $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$.

Comment: $z\to\mathrm{Re} z+i\,|\mathrm{Im} z|$, easy to check with Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: "An example of a function that is analytic only on the upper-half plane"? Please make this notion clear and precise.

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{izn^2}$$

converges for $\Im(z)>0$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: A series representation can diverge at a point, while the function still having an analytic continuation to that point.