# Fabry's Gap Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand Fabry's Gap Theorem and started with [this print](https://www.mathematik.uni-rostock.de/storages/uni-rostock/Alle_MNF/Mathematik/Struktur/Lehrstuehle/Algebra/papers/Fabry.pdf).

I have 2 questions. For one, what does he mean by saying "To obtain Fabry’s gap theorem from this theorem, we can choose the sequence of all nonvanishing coefficents"? I mean for these many sequence members, wouldn't the amount $N_l$ within $[(1-\theta)k_l,(1+\theta)k_l]$ violate the condition $N_l/k_l \to 0$ as $N_l \approx 2\theta k_l$?

The other question is with regard to the proof of theorem 2. Why is it sufficient to prove, that $f$ is singular at $z=1$? I guess you can always rotate $z$ by a suitable choice of coefficients, but even for functions that have a natural boundary at $|z|=1$, not every point on the unit circle is a singularity. For example, the function $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2^k}$$ only has singularities, if $x$ is of the form $x=e^{i 2\pi \, k/2^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. These numbers are dense on the unit circle, but still, there should be points that are not singular.

Comment: Regarding your second question, yes, you rotate to prove other points are singular. Your comment about $\sum x^{2^k}$ is not correct. You are remembering that one proves that those points that you mention are singular. This is only a feature of the proof, that of being easy to prove that those points are singular, but that implies that all other points are singular too. Once a function is regular at a point, then it is regular on a neighborhood of that point. Since that set is dense in the circle, then no point of the circle can be regular.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is important to keep in mind that regular means holomorphic in an open neighbourhood. However, I'm confused about the notion regular=singular. Singular can only be a true singularity (like a pole, an essential singularity or a branch cut), while the use of regular here is associated with the open neighbourhood being holomorphic. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you call a 'true singularity'. I guess you can dump a lot of cases into the notion of 'essential singularity'. Regular at $z=a$ means that the function is equal to a power series on a neighborhood of $a$. Singular mean not-regular. The function can even be smooth (have partial derivatives of all orders) on the unit circle and still be singular on all of it.

Comment: Isn't an essential singularity pretty well defined to be a laurent series with non-terminating principal part? Do you have an example for "The function can even be smooth (have partial derivatives of all orders) on the unit circle and still be singular on all of it."? Like $$f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|}} \, ?$$ But that function wouldn't be holomorphic inside...

Comment: No, you need to review the hypothesis of Laurent series expansions. You need a function that is analytic in an anulus. Don't confuse the study of isolated singularities done in introduction to complex analysis, with what can happen in more general cases. The classic example is $\sum_k z^{k!}/k^2$. As you can see, lots of gaps to make it singular, but the $k^2$ ensures uniform convergence and with it differentiability.

Comment: How "with it differentiability"? Isn't $\sum_k k!/k^2 \, z^{k!-1}$ blowing up on the unit circle?

Comment: $|z|^{k!}=1$ on the unit circle. Very likely there is some post somewhere here already doing the computations.

Comment: Yes, even $|z|=1$ on the unit circle, but that is besides the point that $\sum_k k!/k^2$ blows up which would make it non-differentiable, or?

Comment: I remembered the example wrong. The example in Markushevich's is $\sum_k z^{2^k}/2^{k^2}$. Couldn't find a post in this site, except [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792864/an-example-of-a-function-that-is-analytic-only-on-the-upper-half-plane?noredirect=1#comment5758521_2792864)

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. It should be infinitely differentiable since $$\left|\partial_z^n \sum_k z^{2^k}/2^{k^2} \right|_{|z|=1} \leq \sum_k |2^k(2^k-1)\cdots(2^k-n+1)|/2^{k^2} \leq \sum_k 2^{nk-k^2}$$ which converges.

Btw, by your previous comment "You need a function that is analytic in an anulus." you do not specifically refer to an extended annulus $r<|z|<R$, but rather a finite radius of convergence (say $|z|>R$ or $|z|<r$, as in your example).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying after the "Btw".

Comment: I was pondering about your statement "No, you need to review the hypothesis of Laurent series expansions. You need a function that is analytic in an anulus." which I was thinking if there was more to it with regard to "annulus" or if you just meant "finite radius of convergence" (as the boundary).

Comment: I mean an annulus (at least). Laurent series come from expanding Cauchy's formula on a circle counterclockwise and on a smaller circle clockwise in an annulus. One gives the regular part, the other the singular part. One can use the number of terms of (the singular part of) Laurent series to classify/study isolated singularities. However, in the case of these singularities all over the unit circle, we don't have an annulus around the singular point to do the same. One could put them in the sack of essential singularities. Up to each author to name them.

Comment: Do you understand the step at theorem 3, where he replaces $n=(1+\delta)k$ by $N_l$? $k$ is an index inside $[(1-\theta)k_l,(1+\theta)k_l]$, or?